# Using resample to calculate an average count for 2 weeks

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I'm trying to use `df.resample` to calculate a 2 week average of incoming volume from a particular CSV file, so the plot should be a flat line for each 2 week span. So far the daily count is working correctly and I think I'm taking the DatetimeIndex and trying to resample in 2 week intervals from the most recent date going back to the end of the dataset. When I try

`open_dt = pd.to_datetime(dsort['Date Opened']).dt.date
 open_dt = open_dt.reset_index().sort_values('Date Opened').set_index('Date Opened').groupby('Date Opened').nunique()
 roll_avg = open_dt.resample('2W').mean()`

i get the following error:

```
Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimeDeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got instance of 'Index'
```

I thought that by resetting the index and setting it to a datetime field this would resolve the issue but that doesnt appear to be the case. I've also tried to initialize another variable that only pulls in the original file but I run into the same problem. This is a working copy of my script with the broken roll_avg included

```
def data_process():#sorts by domain and team
data_merge = data_extract()
domains  = data_merge.groupby('PWx Domain')
for domain in domains.groups.items():
    dsort = (data_merge.loc[domain[1]])
    dsort.to_csv('output\\'+str(domain[0])+'.csv')
    open_dt = pd.to_datetime(dsort['Date Opened']).dt.date
    open_dt = open_dt.reset_index().sort_values('Date Opened').set_index('Date Opened').groupby('Date Opened').nunique()
    d_avg = open_dt.mean().round(0).item()
    roll_avg = open_dt.resample('2W').mean()
    print(roll_avg)
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle(domain[0]+' Avg='+str(d_avg), fontsize=14)
    ax = plt.plot(open_dt,color='b', marker='o', linestyle='-') 
    ax = plt.plot(roll_avg, color = 'r', linestyle = '--') 
    fig.savefig('output\\'+domain[0]+'_Overall.png')
    plt.close()
```

Here is the head of the file being read in(data_merge)

```
       Client #                       Solution     Solution Family  \
0     81983  Ambulatory EHR ASP  Physician Practice
1     17235  Ambulatory EHR ASP  Physician Practice
2     17235  Ambulatory EHR ASP  Physician Practice
3     17235     Practice Management  Physician Practice
4     17235     Practice Management  Physician Practice

                      Team       SR #      Date Opened PWx Domain
0    PWx Mill Response ASP  416700000  6/20/2017 19:27   CPHYB_PR
1              Core T1 PWx  416700000  6/20/2017 18:33        NaN
2              Core T1 PWx  416700000  6/20/2017 18:33   CPHYB_PR
3  Claim Generation T3 PWx  416680000  6/19/2017 15:09        NaN
4  Claim Generation T3 PWx  416680000  6/19/2017 15:09   CPHYB_PR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index of `dt.date` objects isn't recognized as a type of date index. It has `dtype('O')`.
`roll_avg` should work if you remove `.dt.date` in

```
open_dt = pd.to_datetime(dsort['Date Opened']).dt.date
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. would you happen to know by chance how I would change my plot from a line to a bar and line? i modified my code to ax = open_dt['index'].plot.bar(color='#007BA7')
    ax = plt.plot(roll_avg, color = 'r', linestyle = '--')?
When I run this i only get the bar chart and not the line following. When i set ax for bar chart and ax2 for the line, I still only get the bar chart plotted. What I'm looking for is a bar chart and line average using the same y axis so I dont think subplots are needed. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.